# Import scipy.stats error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

So I want to import scipy.stats, for whatever reason when I type :

```
import scipy
```

it works just fine, no error, but when I type :

```
import scipy.stats
```

Suddenly I got an error :

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "G:/Python Practice/Gui Int/apa.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python Practice/Gui Int/apa.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.stats'; 'scipy' is not a package
```

I try another such as scipy.io and it's error as well, can I ask what is wrong? is my scipy installation broken or something?? Thank you very much

Comment: What about `from scipy import stats`?

Comment: Have you tried to use any other module from scipy?

Comment: Thanks for the help, somehow I named a py file scipy.py, deleted it and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of the error clearly shows one of the files in your directory setup is shadowing the `scipy` package:

> `'scipy' is not a package`

Well, `scipy` is a package.

You have a file called `scipy.py` in your directory, and that's why the first import works while the second does not.

Comment: Thank you, somehow I named a py file scipy.py, deleted it and it works!!